# Repository pattern on Python

Tags: python, repository-pattern

I'm new to python and I'm comming from the c# world.

Over there it seemed like the repository pattern was the way to go, but I am having trouble finding any tutorials of how to best do this on Python.

**edit** I understand that it can be implemented, I'm just wondering if there is any reason why I am finding close to nothing for how to go about doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please rephrase your question. In python, you can use implement any design pattern you want, but depending on situation you might not want/need to.

Comment: For people familiar with Python but not C#, it would help if you could give a brief description of that repository pattern. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't immediately familiar with the "repository pattern", so I looked it up.  It appears to be the idea of putting a more general API, like a dictionary-like key/value lookup, in front of a database or other data store.  It seems that the idea is to add an additional layer of abstraction that can allow multiple types of data sources (like both a relational database and a CVS file) to be accessed transparently via a common API.

Given this definition, I can think of no reason why this design pattern wouldn't be equally applicable to a problem addressed with Python vs any other programming language.